# No background music while playing on xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I am using following code: mY Sound is placed in myapp/Shared Resources/background_music.aiff

```
@synthesize window = _window;
- (void)dealloc
{
    [backgroundSound release];
    [_window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    sleep(3);
     //this variable can be named differently

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/background_music.aiff",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;

    backgroundSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

     backgroundSound.numberOfLoops = -1;
    //>> this will allow the file to //play an infinite number of times */

    return YES;
}



@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>{
    AVAudioPlayer *backgroundSound;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@end
```

There are no errors and there is no looping sound.Kindly tell me what is going on.

Best Regards

Comment: Nothing to do with the problem, but using `sleep(3);` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will cause some great problems. Because if your app does not start fast enough iOS will kill it. It's better overlay the rootviewcontroller with the `default.png` and removing it when your app is fully loaded.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle no sound ever

Comment: Does logging the url of the sound return correctly?

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle I dONT see any errors in the log

Comment: I'm not asking if there are errors, I'm asking if when you log the file path of the sound file it produces the correct result.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle Fixed it... added play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i added `[background play];` and it has started working fine..... that wasn't mentioned in the tutorial which i was following..

Answer (score 0):

```
 player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
    if(player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying)
        [player stop];
    [player play];
```